# Import markdown files dynamically with Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm looking for a solution that lets me render markdown dynamically, based on the query string. At the moment I render markdown like this, in React + Vite:

```
import some other stuff...
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent } from '../content/blog1.md';
const BlogPost = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  return (
    <Base>
      <PageTitle title={`title of blog ${params.blogId}`} />
      <ReactComponent />
    </Base>
  );
};
export default BlogPost;
```

What I would like is to pass the `blogId` to the import path like:

```
import { ReactComponent } from `../content/blog${params.blogId}.md`
```

Such that the correct file is imported on each `/blog/*` route. I tried this by lazy loading the markdown like:

```
const path = `../content/blog${params.blogId}.md`;
const Markdown = React.lazy(() => import(path));
```

But this raises errors and when I log `Markdown` I see

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy), _payload: {…}, _init: ƒ}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy)
_init: ƒ lazyInitializer(payload)
_payload: {_status: -1, _result: ƒ}
```

Which appears to be empty. What would be a solution to accomplish this?

Comment: Just struggled with the same myself, ended up just using showdown to generate html from markdown and hosting those. The issue with your lazy import I believe is due to not knowing at build time what files should be included. I went through basically all markdown libraries for vite and rollup, some worked, but had exact same issue as you with multiple files. vite-plugin-ssr could solve it, but didnt like that – too much stuff for a simple landing page. Though if this is blog you want SEO for, having ready made html files is probably nice (SSG). You could consider Next, Gatsby or Jekyll.

Comment: Everything works when I place the markdown in the public folder so the lazy loading is not the right solution here. Might check out a SSR solution like you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense since vite/rollup doesn't know what files to include at build time, due to the variable in the lazy loading path. Then providing them in the public folder forces them to exist.

Answer (score 14):

I had also issue when importing assets. In my case `.md` import failed.

`import Article from './assets/article.md';`

> Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content
> contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate
> plugins to handle the .md file format, or if it's an asset, add
> "**/*.md" to `assetsInclude` in your configuration

So I solved it adding `assetsInclude: ['**/*.md']` setting to vite.config.js (for my .md files)

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  plugins: [react()],
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.md']
  ...
})
```

Eventually this started to work:

```
import("./assets/article.md").then(res => {
    fetch(res.default)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
})
```

Docs are here:https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html
Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: it works well with md file. thanks!

Comment: I think you can import file as string


`import("./assets/article.md?raw")`


Docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string